# Is it possible to set a Timer with condition in Mongoose OS?

Tags: mongoose-os

I am familiar with using `mgos_msleep(value)` or `mgos_usleep(value)`. However, using sleep is not good for the device.

Can someone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Specify the question. Enter some code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the architecture of the system and use case with you.

The sleep call in mongoose OS does not cause a busy wait. The sleep call conveys to OS to not schedule the particular process until the sleep duration is over. The 'mgos_usleep' function is a sleep with greater resolution (microseconds) which should have very less impact, however this in turn is based on your requirement / use case.

With respect to timer, the Mongoose OS supports both software timers and hardware timers. The decision to use either software timer or hardware timer is in turn based on the application requirement with you.

*The mgos_set_timer sets up a software timer with milliseconds timeout and the respective callback.* The software timer frequency is specified in milliseconds and the number of software timers is not limited.The software timer callback is executed in mongoose task context. This timer seems to be with fairly low accuracy and high jitter.

*The mgos_set_hw_timer sets up a hardware timer with microseconds timeout and the respective callback.* The hardware timer callback is executed in the ISR context and hence the actions are limited due it. The hardware timers or counters shall be available as per the type of processor that you use, hence you may need to have a look at the datasheet. Accordingly, the number of hardware timers is limited and the frequency is specified in microseconds.